# when then return doesn't work properly in junit

Tags: java, junit

I have these functions

```
    public void getResults(Profile profile, Query query, Params params, String UUID) {
        Map<String, Object> inputParams = new HashMap<>();
        String whereClause = formulateWhereCondition(params.getOperators(), inputParams);
        String finalQuery = formatSql(query, params, profile);
        finalQuery = finalQuery.replace(WHERECLAUSE, whereClause);
        searchOutput =  saveResults(profile,params, UUID, finalQuery, inputParams,query,true);
        ----
        ----
    }
    
    private void saveResults(Profile profile,Params params, String UUID,  String finalQuery, Map<String, ? > paramsMap , Query query,Boolean initialCall){
        String whereClause = formulateWhereCondition(params.getOperators(), (Map<String, Object>) paramsMap);
        finalSql = finalSql.replace(WHERECLAUSE, whereClause);
        Result<List<Map<String, ?>>> result =  service.getResults(finalSql, paramsMap,query, params.getPagination());
        ----
        ----
    }
```

I made this test

```
@RunWith(ControlsSpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class TestClass extends BaseTest {
    @InjectMocks Controller controller
    @Mock Service service
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("s1_txt", "txt");
        data.put("s2_txt", "txt");
        results = new ArrayList<>();
        results.add(data);
       result = Result.<List<Map<String, ?>>>builder() 
               .data(results)
               .identifier("id") 
               .totalCount(123)
               .build();
    }   

   @Test
   public void testTest() {       
   Mockito.when(service.getResults(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),ArgumentMatchers.any(Map.class), ArgumentMatchers.any(Query.class), ArgumentMatchers.any(PagingInfo.class)))
   .thenReturn(result);

    controller.generateResults(testSearchProfile, query, searchInputParameters, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    }

}
```

The idea is when `service.getResults(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),ArgumentMatchers.any(Map.class), ArgumentMatchers.any(Query.class), ArgumentMatchers.any(PagingInfo.class))` is executed - it doesnt return the result - it return null instead

any idea ?

Comment: My initial thought would be that the real call to `service.getResults` does not match your expected call and so `result` is not what is returned, but the 'default' value for the return type. Also, your definition of `getResults` seems to show that it is a void method, in this case,  which should not be mocked in this way. NB: Its really confusing when methods called `getX` are void methods (since they do not get anything). You'd be better off 'verifying' that a void method was called e.g. Mockito.verify(service).getResults(any(), any, ...);

Comment: Does your Code under test eventually pass `null` as one or more of the parameters to the mocked method?

Comment: `getResults` is a `void` method and doesn't return anything

Comment: @TimothyTruckle No - it doesnt

Comment: @QBrute i am talking about service.getResults in saveResults method

Answer (score 1):

Since your method is a void method you should check that it *was* called by using a verify step AFTER the call to your code under test.

```
@Test
public void testTest() {       
   
  controller.generateResults(testSearchProfile, query, searchInputParameters, UUID.randomUUID().toString());

  Mockito.verify(service).getResults(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.any(Map.class), ArgumentMatchers.any(Query.class), ArgumentMatchers.any(PagingInfo.class));

}
```